# Multiple validation groups in entities in Symfony - how?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

How do we assign a rule to multiple validation groups, is this correct:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
 * @Assert\NotBlank (groups={"registration, employee"})
 */
private $password;
```

? Should we use a comma or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost.. ;-)

You have one value `"registration, employee"`, but you want to have array of values, so every group should be in its own quotation marks, like: `"registration", "employee"`

Try this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
 * @Assert\NotBlank (groups={"registration", "employee"})
 */
private $password;
```

Comment: thank you!  <- Btw even even if this is longer than 15 characters I still get the "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length" message o_O

Comment: OK, I get the "15 characters" thing, @calling_someone doesn't count :) It even isn't included in a result message (if correct).